# How to set Technicolor TG799vn v2 in bridge mode

Tags: router

Does anyone know how to set a Technicolor TG799vn v2 router in bridge mode? 
I can't find a place to configure it in the web interface.

Answer (score 1):

The Technicolor router is delivered by my internet service provider (Telia, Denmark). I finally called them and they changed the router to bridge mode for a fee of 300 DKK.